# Code stopped working. Gives me a `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'items'` error

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I'm using spotify's API for my web app. i created a search bar that asks for the query and the type of that query (eg. track, album, artist) as required by spotify. The code for searching for an album was working just fine until a few hours ago when it stopped and started giving me the following error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'items'` upon a closer look the terminal points out that the problem is with the following line `{% for k, v in value.items() %}` it should be noted that i didn't change a thing in the code, and as i mentioned it was working just fine, i keep going back to spotify's console to check the data i recieve and whether there's a logic error in my code but i can't seem to find one. **Actually** i'm facing the same problem with searching for artists. but that's for another question. for now, the problem is my search for albums.

for a better understanding of the data recieved you can check out spotify's search console: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
        <section class="wrapper">
            <div class="search-res">
                <h1 class="header">{{query}}</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="records" id="tracks">
                        {% set info = [] %}

                        {% if q_type == "album" %}
                            {% for record in results['albums']['items'] %}
                                {% for key, value in record.items() %}
                                    {% if key == "artists" %}
                                        {% for k, v in value.items() %}
                                            {% if k == "name" %}
                                                {{info.append(v) or ""}}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% if key == "name" %}
                                        {{info.append(value)}}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% if key == "id" %}
                                        {{info.append(value)}}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% if key == "external_urls" %}
                                        {% for k, v in value.items() %}
                                            {% if k == "spotify" %}
                                                {{info.append(v) or ""}}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% if key == "images" %}
                                        {% for k, v in value[1].items() %}
                                            {% if k == "url" %}
                                                {{info.append(v) or ""}}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {{info}}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Python?

Comment: This is part of the template that is rendered in the search route. The web app is written in python yes. And I'm using flask as my framework. I added python and flask as tags because i believed them to be relevant info. I can see how they can be deemed the opposite tho.

Comment: do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary has a function `items()`. If you have a dictionary like this `{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}`, dic.items() will give you a list of tuple `[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')]`.

This function helps us to iterate the dictionary with key and value.

Your error is `'list object' has no attribute 'items'`. This shows that `value` is a list, not a dictionary. Since you are calling a dictionary function (items()) for a list, you got this error.

You have to debug line by line to get a better understanding.
Remove everything after this line.

```
{% for k, v in value.items() %}
```

And just print the `value` to check the data type. I hope it will be a list. Just add this below line and check the output.

```
{{ value }}
```

But since your copied this code directly from their website, there should not be any error in the code. Anyways just check the data structure as explained above.